# Is int? a value type or a reference type?

Tags: c#, int, value-type, reference-type

This question is more about adding a `?` to a value type than about `int?`

In C# an `int` is a value type.
Is `int?` a value type or a reference type?

In my opinion it should be a reference type as it can be `null`.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx

Comment: The `null` support for `Nullable<T>` is behind the scenes trickery on the part of the language team and compiler.

Comment: int? === Nullable<int>. Nullable<T> is a value type, thus, int? is a value type. I believe the Nullable<T> type was added for use with database integration, where strongly typed data fields (in this case int) can be 0 or greater, or null...all of which are valid in the context of a database.

Comment: nice answer series0ne

Comment: Your logic is: `null` is always the "refers to nothing" value of a reference type, `null` is a legal value for a nullable value type, therefore nullable value types are reference types. This syllogism would be correct if the two premises were true, but the first premise is false.  A nullable value type is nothing more than a bool that indicates nullity glued to a non-nullable value. If the bool is false then the value is considered to be null. The null value of a nullable value type is not the same bits as a null reference; they are completely different.

Comment: As far as I know, '?' is the 'nullable' operator. It is normally used in value types in C#.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`int?` is equivalent to [`Nullable<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) which means it is a [struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx).

So that means it is a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

> In my opinion it should be a reference type as it can be null.

Your assumption is wrong. From documentation;

> Nullable structure represents a value type that **can be assigned
>   null**. The Nullable structure supports using only a value type as
>   a nullable type because reference types are nullable by design.

So it has 2 values;

1. The value of data
2. Boolean value which determines the values has been set or not. ([`Nullable<T>.HasValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx))

Comment: [SerializableAttribute]
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct

thx!

Comment: I used reflection to examine the properties of a type .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsValueType) and properties included nullables.  So, that backs up what you're saying.

Answer (score 2):

[Nullable types are instances of the System.Nullable struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) Hence `int?` is a Value Type.

Answer (score 1):

`int?` is not a reference type. It is a `struct` (value type).

It has its own value like a normal int plus an additional "null" value. With Nullable types, you can check if it has a value using `HasValue`.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT* I should've started with this example in the 1st place:

Think about *enums*. Every *enum* we write automatically extends `Enum`, which is a class.
Hence, value types we write extend a class written by the .NET team which is a reference type.

You can split the world of types in two ways:

- whether they contain the `null` value or not
- whether they are value types or not

All combinations are possible in theory. If I'm not mistaking, in C# at least, the combination of reference types which cannot be `null` yields an empty set. There is no example for that combination.

Basically all other 3 combinations are possible:

- types which can be null and are value types
- types which cannot be null and are value types
- types which can be null and are reference types

The nature of being either a value type or a reference type has nothing to do with `null` (at least in the way languages should be designed and used, not in the way of the actual engineering details underneath).

Value types are types which cause assignments between variables, parameters and fields to do full cloning of the instance.
Reference types are types which don't do that.

That has basically nothing to do with `null` *or* with the type of memory which is occupied by the instances (be it stack, heap or something else).